# How can I prevent first-child CSS from also affecting the second child in my HTML Table?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

I spruced up my HTML table a bit with some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154353/how-can-i-bold-specific-html-rows-and-columns-with-css-or-html/24154794#24154794).

...but now I want to prevent the CSS:

```
tr:first-child { color: skyblue }
```

...from affecting row 1 in addition to row 0.

To see what I mean, see the latest update [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/LU7qm/13/) - the "I eat tacos" line should be orange, not skyblue.

### UPDATE

I'm happy with the latest [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/LU7qm/19/); thanks all!

Comment: [Derp](http://jsfiddle.net/LU7qm/15/)

Comment: Use `th { color: skyblue }` instead of `tr:first-child`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `thead` to your CSS:

```
thead tr:first-child { color: skyblue }
```

EDIT: though you don't really need the `first-child` and could just use `thead tr` since you only have one row in your `thead`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LU7qm/14/)